# Not able to install sbt in windows 7

Tags: build, sbt

I installed sbt in my windows 7 machine  from http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Windows.html using msi installer

After installing if i go to Command prompt and while checking the installed sbt version i get the below error

```
C:\>sbt --version
Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
            module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\rajasure\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy
.xml

      -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

      C:\Users\rajasure\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\jars\jan
si.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1
.11.pom

      -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1
.11.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/j
ansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi
 /jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


  :::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo1.mav
 en.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo1.mav
en.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.type
 safe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.scal
a-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-     snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml


 :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
(see C:\Users\suren\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
  Error: Could not retrieve jansi 1.11
```

Could somebody help me on fixing this error? I really need some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem! this solved!

" Looks like the dependency manager has a problem with the non-ASCII characters in your user name.

Try adding -Dsbt.global.base=C:/some/other/path to the command line of the SBT process. This will relocate files from the default location of %USERHOME%/.sbt. "

Comment: @ Venkat How do we add that in command line? Are you saying that include that line in C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf\sbtconf.txt

Comment: I tried setting the property in windows command prompt   and i still get the same error  C:\>set  -Dsbt.global.base= C:\some_sbt

C:\>sbt
Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11

Comment: Have you found the solution? I also have the same problem. Not sure how to add the line? I am totally a beginner with Scala

Comment: I really don't see what leads you to think it's a problem to non ascii characters - I don't see any. I havae same problem, tried to move the sbt directory under c:\temp\ and I have exactly the same issue. plus it gives me a warning when I try to pass the parameter : invalid system property 'sbt.global.base'